# jquery each loop in a each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some divs that i use as containers, i want to loop over them and then loop over the items in it.

so not `$('.stackContainer .stackItem').each(` but something like this:

```
// setup stacks
$('.stackContainer').each(function(containerIndex) {
    //console.log($(this));
    console.log(containerIndex);

    $(this).('.stackItem').each(function(itemIndex) {
        console.log(itemIndex);     
    }
});
```

Only then working.
How is this possible?

Comment: Open your browser's developer console and you will know why your code is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('.stackContainer').each(function(containerIndex) {
    //console.log($(this));
    console.log(containerIndex);

    $(this).find('.stackItem').each(function(itemIndex) {
        console.log(itemIndex);     
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try `find()` method:

```
$('.stackContainer').each(function(containerIndex) {
    //console.log($(this));
    console.log(containerIndex);

    $(this).find('.stackItem').each(function(itemIndex) {
        console.log(itemIndex);     
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways of doing this, as other answers have indicated. Here's one solution: http://jsfiddle.net/cezHH/3/

```
$(".stackContainer").each(function(stackIndex) {
    $(this).children().css('class', '.stackItem').each(function(itemIndex) {
        $(this).html($(this).html() + "=>" + itemIndex);
    });
});​
```

Alternatively, if all you want to do is iterate over all the `.stackItem` divs in the order in which they appear on the page, and you don't actually care about the parent `.stackContainer` divs, then you could just do `$('.stackItem').each(function(index) { ... });`

The reason to nest the loop that iterates over the `.stackItem` divs is if you want the `itemIndex` variable to reset to zero each time you switch parent containers.

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, for performance reasons, you should avoid using jQuery's each() if it's possible that the collection will be of any size:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance/

http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop